# Laravel How to check if request is null that sent by datatable ajax

Tags: laravel, datatable

I want to check if requests that using for filtering are null, so if null then show all data in datatable otherwise filter the results depend on the requested values

here controller

```
  public function getCustomFilterData(Request $request)
  {
   $arrStart = explode("/", Input::get('start_date'));
    $arrEnd = explode("/", Input::get('end_date'));
    $start = Carbon::create($arrStart[2], $arrStart[0], $arrStart[1], 0, 0, 0);
    $end = Carbon::create($arrEnd[2], $arrEnd[0], $arrEnd[1], 23, 59, 59);

$min = $request->start_amount;
  $max = $request->end_amount;

     $vendorTableName= with(new Vendors())->getTable();
   $categoryTableName= with(new Excategories())->getTable();
 $orders =Checks::select(["checks.*","vendors.vendor_name","excategories.category_name"])->Wherebetween('amount',[$min,$max])->between($start, $end)->leftJoin($vendorTableName,$vendorTableName.".vendor_id","=","checks.vendor_id")->leftJoin($categoryTableName,$categoryTableName.".category_id","=","checks.category_id");
return Datatables::of($orders)->make( TRUE );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to determine if a value is present on the request and is not empty, you may use [the has](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#input-trimming-and-normalization) method:

```
if ($request->has('name')) {
    //
}
```

---

```
public function getCustomFilterData(Request $request)
{
    $vendorTableName = with(new Vendors())->getTable();
    $categoryTableName = with(new Excategories())->getTable();
    $orders = Checks::select(["checks.*","vendors.vendor_name","excategories.category_name"]);

    if($request->has('start_amount') && $request->has('end_amount')) {
        $min = $request->start_amount;
        $max = $request->end_amount;

        $orders->Wherebetween('amount',[$min,$max]);
    }

    if($request->has('start_date') && $request->has('end_date')) {
        $arrStart = explode("/", Input::get('start_date'));
        $arrEnd = explode("/", Input::get('end_date'));
        $start = Carbon::create($arrStart[2], $arrStart[0], $arrStart[1], 0, 0, 0);
        $end = Carbon::create($arrEnd[2], $arrEnd[0], $arrEnd[1], 23, 59, 59);

        $orders->between($start, $end);
    }

    $orders = $orders->leftJoin($vendorTableName,$vendorTableName.".vendor_id","=","checks.vendor_id")
                    ->leftJoin($categoryTableName,$categoryTableName.".category_id","=","checks.category_id")
                    ->get();

    return Datatables::of($orders)->make( TRUE );
}
```

Comment: Method filled does not exist.

Comment: this is working if if ($request->has(['start_amount', 'end_amount'])) {

        $min = $request->start_amount;
        $max = $request->end_amount;

        $orders->Wherebetween('amount',[$min,$max]);
    }
if ($request->has(['start_date', 'end_date'])) {

Answer (score 0):

Though I am a bit late but if anyone wants to check for all the values of the `$request`then it can be done like this

```
if( !empty($request->has( $request->all() )) ){
    //the value is edited,the above condition returns true if $request has value
}
Else{
    return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'No Value Edited.');

}
```

In the **View**

```
@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <strong>Enjoy!&emsp;</strong>{{ $message }}.
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    @if ($message = Session::get('warning'))
                        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <strong>Caution!&emsp;</strong>{{ $message }}.
                        </div>
                    @endif
```